# Capitalizing hi in a text

Tags: questions

Is the word "hi" capitalized or not in the following usage:

"I said hi to Jim as I passed him on the way to school."

Comment: "I said 'Hi!' to Jim as I passed him on the way to school."

Comment: Your sentence is just fine as it is.

Answer (score 2):

> The Choice Rests With You.

Some usage examples from major publications:

- “You drive around the neighborhood and say **‘hi’** to your friends,” she said. (Washington Times,Jul 19, 2015)
- Saying goodbye, Friesen relays a message to Eldredge: "Tell him I said **hi** and that, by the way, we still have the body."
  (Los Angeles Times,Jul 16, 2015)
- They said even a friendly "**Hi**, how are you?" between parents was felt to be important in creating a positive atmosphere at school.
  (BBC,Jul 1, 2015)

Answer (score 0):

No, you only needs caps at the start of a sentence, or for proper nouns such as a place name. Caps within a sentence could be used for emphasis, but it is a bit confusing.